# How to run my script from another script and wait for finish?

Tags: php

I need to call a script called build_report.php, pass in a URL variable named partno and wait until it is finished before continuing.

This script builds a report and then an email is sent out to our customer so I don't want the email sent until the report is generated.

Is this possible?

Which should I use exec or cURL?

Comment: Can't you just use `include()`?

Comment: will that actually *run* the script? How will I know it is finished?

Comment: Let the script generate a known environment variable or a value therein. The waiting script checks for the existence of these environment variables and reacts.

Comment: If you're going to wait for the script to finish, why not just turn the whole thing into a function call? Define a function in build_report.php (accepting whatever parameters you were sending through the URL) and include build_report.php in your main script. Your main script calls the function, then sends the email when the function returns.

Comment: It is basis for a module in Prestashop e-commerce system. It will be called in an "event hook" so I'm not sure I can do that there.

I seem to have an idea to use cURL to do this and, so far, it is looking good.

Comment: grossvogel, I want to know if I can have a class within a class in PHP.

Comment: Would this construct work:
<pre>
class ReportGenerator extends Module
{
  function BuildReport($partno) {
    require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    MyPDF extends TCPDF 
    {
      // class methods, etc here
    }
    $pdf = new MyPDF;
    // get the data and build the report here...
  }

  function hookUpdateOrderStatus($params) {
  // If the order status was changed to "Payment accepted"
    if ($params['newOrderStatus'] == 2) {
      $partno = $params['partno']; // or something similar
      BuildReport($partno);
    } 
  }
}</pre>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a local script, exec() or system() will do the trick.

Comment: ...except that the script may have server-specific code, such as `apache_request_headers()` or `getallheaders()`

Comment: No specific stuff like that. How will I know it is finished?

Comment: @MB34 `exec()` blocks until finished.

Comment: how do I pass in URL variable using exec?

Comment: See the command line interface help for PHP.  I think its just a matter of passing it in as a command line argument.

Comment: @MB34 If you call `php build_report.php foo bar`, then `$argc[1]` will be `foo` and `$argc[2]` will be `bar`.

Comment: Not going to use exec, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can call ajax request and get response from that.After getting response you can send another ajax request to send email.This code needs Jquery.

Here is sample code for send ajax request using php.It is simple.

```
  var passdata ="partno=5"
  $.ajax({
        url: "yourpath/build_report.php",
        data:passdata ,
        async:false, 
        type: "POST",
        success: function(response){

               if(response=="true"){
                   /* call send email script */
                          emaildata="name=vcvx"+'email="vxvx@yyy.com";
                          $.ajax({
                                     url: "yourpath/build_report.php",
                                    data:emaildata,
                                     async:true, 
                                     type: "POST",
                                      success: function(response){
                                     }

                              }); 

                 }

         } });
```